# Call another JSP from the current JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jboss

I have to call one or another JSP-page from the current JSP-page based on a boolean value.

Pseudo example:

```
if(!found) { 
    // call one jsp    
} else {    
    // call other jsp
}
```

I have tried `<a>`, `<frameset>`, `<iframe>`, and `<include>` tags.

I'm using Jboss as the application server.

Comment: your question in unclear

Comment: Do you want to `include` or `redirect` jsp?

Answer (score 1):

Call is not really explicit enough. You can :

- forward to the other jsp with `<jsp:forward>` tag => you pass the hand to the other jsp and never come back
- include the other jsp as source with `@include` directive : all page scoped variable will be available in the included jsp - in fact it will be included at compile time (jsp are translated to java source and then compiled) but only executed if condition is true => you share all scope variable with included JSP and come back to caller after
- include the other jsp with `<jsp:include>` tag : under the hood you call `RequestDispatcher.include`, so the other jsp will have its own set of page scoped variable and will only be included if condition is true => you actually *call* a different JSP with its own page context  and come back to caller after